# snmpbulkget in parallel is causing an error to occur

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, snmp, xargs

Trying to query a ton of devices with a simple output (in this test case; model identification)

My code works fine when running individually; its when I attempt to parallelize it...errors occur

Script file named "**get**":

```sh
\#!/bin/bash

model="$(snmpbulkget -r1 -t1 -v2c -c test_comm $1 1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13 | grep -m1 STRING | sed 's/.*://' | sed 's/ "//' | sed 's/"//')" &&
echo "$1,$model"
```

Using a single test; works with no issue:

```
./get 10.23.50.117
10.23.50.117,N9K-C93108TC-EX
```

Trying to parallelize (even with just 10 processes):

```
xargs -d " " -P 10 --arg-file=check ./get
snmp_build: unknown failure
snmpbulkget: Error building ASN.1 representation (Can't build OID for variable)
```

Using the -L arg flag in xargs causes each IP in the list to be hit 10x instead of 10 IPs once each.

```
cat check_out | sort
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.1,NY-SW1
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.12.0.4,NY-SW2
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
10.14.14.8,CY-WAN-SW1
```

Comment: Edited post with output while using -L argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that of understanding the arguments to the "xargs" utility.
You did not tell us what your "check" file looks like.
When I try it with the correct arguments, it works:

```
% ./get 10.201.0.110
10.201.0.110,..System Bootstrap, Version 11.0(10c), SOFTWARE..Copyright (c) 1986-1996 by cisco Systems..

% ./get 10.1.120.142
10.1.120.142,BOOT_NORMAL

% cat check
10.201.0.110
10.1.120.142 

% xargs -L 1 -P 10 --arg-file=check ./get
10.201.0.110,..System Bootstrap, Version 11.0(10c), SOFTWARE..Copyright (c) 1986-1996 by cisco Systems..
10.1.120.142,BOOT_NORMAL
```

Comment: My check file is similar to yours just with 400+ IP addresses

Comment: Well, then it should work, but AGAIN, you don't show your EXACT invocation or contents of the file. To solve this quickly, you should be able to reduce your file, show the exact contents and invocation. In the future, it is ALWAYS faster to start with a working example than a non-working example.